# Extract msi to Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, extract

I was developing a small software and my laptop stolen when I was traveling but I had no backup. At this moment I have only installation file that I make by setup and deployment from visual studio 2015.

I develop this software program using vb.net

Can I extract the installation file to source code ?

I have two files

1. Microsoft installer I mean msi
2. exe

Can anybody help me to extract it?

Thankx in advance

Comment: You can decompile the executable, although no decompiler can exactly translate IL back to the original source code; things will be different. In the future, use source control.

Comment: ... and backup!

Comment: Thank you Daniel mann and Oliver Jacot. I tried to decompile using reflector but it is showing error with my exe file and msi file also